# Call using Facetime audio only

Tags: iphone, ios, facetime

I would like to be using Facetime for audio calls only. When I open some contact on my iPhone I can see something like on the picture attached. The intuition tells me those two buttons within Facetime row should call using either video call or audio-only call. However it doesnt matter what button I click, it always starts the video call.
How can I start the audio-only call from contact card, like the one below? Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're hitting the 'audio' button correctly? I found that it needs to be tapped very precisely.

Sometimes iOS incorrectly assumes that the tap goes to the whole FaceTime row, which is then highlighted in gray during the tap and starts a FaceTime video call.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

1. Open FaceTime app
2. Press the `+` located in the top-right of screen
3. Select the contact(s) you want to audio FaceTime call
4. An audio option will be visible (big green button)

Note: These instructions are from [here](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-make-audio-facetime-call-on-iphone/).

Comment: Nice method, but the question specifically asks for *from contact card*. I might also recommend "Hey Siri, FaceTime audio call Bailee"